# columna autoincrementable con letra y numeros dependiendo de otra columna

Tags: mysql

Quiero crear una columna autoincrementable que reconozca el tipo de comprobante que se emitira.
Tengo la siguiente table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|id  | numcomprobante  | tipocomprobante  | iddetalleventa   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | B00-0001        | BOLETA           | 1                |
| 2  | B00-0002        | BOLETA           | 2                |
| 3  | F00-0001        | FACTURA          | 3                |
| 4  | B00-0003        | BOLETA           | 4                |
```

Como ven, las primeras dos filas que son boletas se emiten en orden incrementable, pero con un prefijo de letra B, como la inicial del tipo de comprobante, sin embargo la tercera fila se reinicia el numero, y el prefijo de letra cambia a otra letra 'F', para luego continuar con la numeracion anterior

Como podria hacerlo con un trigger?

Comment: Aunque no imposible, implementar esto tal cómo lo pides tendría un efecto negativo en el tiempo que toma para hacer los inserts, porque tendrías que recorrer la tabla para cada insert para averiguar la secuencia que debes usar. Adicionalmente, hay la complicación adicional de cómo manejar 2 inserts concurrentes. ¿Cómo te asegurarías de no crear un `numcomprobante` duplicado? Para evitar mucha complicación, sería mucho más sencillo si no requieres que la secuencia numérica se base en el tipo de comprobante.

Comment: Raphael, esta problemática según mi experiencia se maneja con una tabla de numeradores por cada tipo de comprobante. Al crear un comprobante, siempre dentro de una transacción, lo primero que debes hacer es obtener el numerador sumarle 1 y actualizar el registro asegurándonos de bloquearlo, para evitar cualquier conflicto con otra transacción concurrente.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function registrar($tipocomprobante,$iddetalleventa)
                     {
                      $sql='SELECT MAX(id) FROM tabla';
                      $resultado = $this->consultar($sql);

                      $numcomprobante="";
                      if($tipocomprobante=="BOLETA"){
                        $numcomprobante="B00-00$resultado+1";
                      }  else {
                        $numcomprobante="F00-00$resultado+1";
                     }

                    $sw = true;
                    $sql= 'INSERT INTO tabla  
                   (numcomprobante,tipocomprobante,iddetalleventa,) 
                    VALUES (  \''.$numcomprobante.'\', 
                   \''.$tipocomprobante.'\', 
                   \''.$iddetalleventa.'\')';


                   $this->conexion->query($sql) or $sw = false;
                   return $sw;
                   }
```